# Watin eval issue

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to use the `Eval()` function of Watin in the following way:

```
ie.DomContainer.Eval("$(\"select[gwtdebugid='signup-flow-choose-timezones']\")");
```

I' using the scape character by it gave me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: '$' is not defined.
```

What is the correct way of formatting this string?

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the closing bracket and quotes.

```
ie.DomContainer.Eval("$(\"select[gwtdebugid='signup-flow-choose-timezones']\")");
```